# Can we tell if a number is prime by the number of its partition ?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Can we tell if a number is prime by  the number of its partition ?

Or in general, how much can we know about a number itself from its partition function ?

I understand that Ramanujan has some observation some properties about congruence of a few numbers.

Just want to know if there are more general results on this.

Comment: Probably not. If there was, this would probably be a lot longer: http://oeis.org/A058698

Answer (score 2):

No, I read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29 and I don't think primality can be determined by partitions. However, it does say you can find out if a number is coprime to 6.